# Re-set alarms on device startup

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a reminder app which show TODO's to the user at their specified time and date. As all alarms set by the app are lost when device is switched off, I put my alarm re-setting logic in a `Broadcast Receiver` as shown below.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public BootReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        List<Todo> todos = fetchTodosFromDatabase();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(......);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemServices(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        for (Todo todo : todos) {
           long timeInMillis = todo.getTime();
           alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest package="............"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:installLocation="internalOnly">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>

    </receiver>
</manifest>
```

The problem is that the signal for `BOOT_COMPLETED` is received quite late in the `BroadcastReceiver` usual time being 2-3 minutes. What if the user has set an alarm between the time phone is rebooted and the time by which the signal is received. Then this alarm will be lost for the user. I know the probability of happening this is quite low but it is not zero. So I tried to find does this happen for the stock `Clock` app also by setting alarm in it. But it was competely unaffected and the alarm goes off as soon as the device reboots. So, is there any way I can receive `BOOT_COMPELTED` signal as soon as the device boots without any delay?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this more complicated than iterating each todo, and checking to see if the alarm was missed, and if so trigger it immediately?

Comment: Yep, something like this would work though it will require some effort. Thanks